# GGPlot is returning different colours to what I specify

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I'm somewhat new to R - and having a really strange issue while trying to produce the following plot

```
worst_death <- df_clean %>%
        group_by(event_cat) %>%
        summarise(Deaths = sum(FATALITIES)
                  , Injuries = sum(INJURIES)) %>%
        ggplot()+
        geom_segment(aes(x=reorder(event_cat,Injuries),xend=reorder(event_cat,Injuries), y=Deaths, yend = Injuries, color="black")) +
        geom_point(aes(x=reorder(event_cat,Injuries), y=Deaths,color="yellow", size=1 ))+
        geom_point(aes(x=reorder(event_cat,Injuries), y=Injuries,color="white", size=1 ))+
        coord_flip()+
        theme_ipsum()+
        theme(legend.position = "none",) +
        xlab("Event Type") +
        ylab("Human Impact")
        
        

worst_death
```

The graph is running perfectly - except the colours and aesthetic options (size etc.) are not returning what I specified.

[image: output]

Strangely enough the colours are red blue and green, rather than yellow black and white.

does anyone know why this might be happening?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can't test this without your data, but the following should work for you:

```r
worst_death <- df_clean %>%
        group_by(event_cat) %>%
        summarise(Deaths = sum(FATALITIES),
                  Injuries = sum(INJURIES)) %>%
        ggplot(aes(x = reorder(event_cat,Injuries), y = Deaths)) +
        geom_segment(aes(xend = reorder(event_cat,Injuries), 
                         y = Deaths, yend = Injuries)) +
        geom_point(color = "yellow", size = 1) +
        geom_point(aes(y = Injuries), color = "white", size = 1) +
        coord_flip() +
        theme_ipsum() +
        theme(legend.position = "none") +
        xlab("Event Type") +
        ylab("Human Impact")
        
worst_death
```

There are a couple of points to note:

- When you use a character string for color *inside* `aes`, ggplot reads it as a single factor level that assigns the geom to a labelled color *grouping*, and will not interpret it as a literal color assignment. If you had a legend in your plot, the key would show the *labels* "white" and "yellow" against the red and blue key dots. You can either add `+ scale_color_identity()` to your plot if you want these labels to be interpreted as literal colors or, more commonly, just bring `color =` *outside* of `aes`, where it is interpreted as an actual color assignment. This is the easiest way to do it if you don't want a legend.
- You should probably bring `size =` outside the `aes` call too, effectively for the same reason. `ggplot` is mapping the number 1 to its default size scale rather than literally making the points size 1.
- The `geom_segment` is black by default, so it doesn't need a color assignment.
- You can save some typing (and hence reduce risk of bugs and make maintenance easier) if you include the default x and y aesthetics in the original `ggplot` call. These are inherited by any subsequent geoms, but can be over-ridden if required.
- When posting a question on SO, please include data as well as code, otherwise no-one can reproduce your problem or test / demonstrate possible solutions. The easiest way to do this in your case is to copy and paste the output of `dput(df_clean)` into your question.